# Is it possible to play animation clips without an Animator in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm looking into Unity animation functionality and am wondering if there's any way to work around the Animator system. Playing clips is fine, but Im looking to hold on certain keyframes in script and eventually attach data for selected keyframes. The animator feels too high level for this type for approach.

Are there any alternatives to the Animator system? I had a look around and saw mentions of Assimp and SimpleAnimation as external support, but they don't seem currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a couple of tests and it looks like I can actually pause on certain frames via the following, without actually working directly on the animator

```
 _playable = AnimationPlayableUtilities.PlayClip(_animator, _clip, out var graph);

_playable.SetSpeed(0.0f);

[...]

// for a specific keyframe
            _playable.SetTime(_step * _clip.length);
```